# Find $\int\limits_0^\infty {x{e^{ - (a{x^2} + b)}}{I_0}\left( {\sqrt {c{x^2} + dx + k} } \right)dx} $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions, laguerre-polynomials

I am trying to find the following integral:

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {x{e^{ - (a{x^2} + b)}}{I_0}\left( {\sqrt {c{x^2} + dx + k} } \right)dx} $

Where, $x,a,b,c,d,k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I_0(.)$ is the modified bessel function of the first kind.

I know there is a basic rule for the, for $k>0$:

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {{x^{2k - 1}}{e^{ - (a{x^2})}}{I_0}\left( {bx} \right)dx}  = \frac{{\Gamma \left( k \right)}}{{2{a^k}}}{L_{ - k}}\left( {\frac{{{b^2}}}{{4a}}} \right)$

Where, $L$ is [Laguerre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) polynomial.

I am having a problem because of the argument inside $I_0(.)$ which is ${\sqrt {c{x^2} + dx + k} }$. Can anyone suggest to me how to do the integration?

Comment: If you expand the Bessel function into its power series, you obtain $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{2^{2k} k!^2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {xe^{ - (ax^2  + b)} (cx^2  + dx + e)^k dx} } .
$$ You may then expand the $k$th power and integrate term-by-term and see if the result can be identified in terms of known (special) functions (e.g., hypergeometric functions).

Comment: You can get rid of the b, which just gives a common factor.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.